# Does $\exists$ a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, f(x) \neq x+c$ s.t. every interval $(a,b)$ contains a point $p$ with gradient 1?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Does there exist a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) \neq x+c$ such that *every* interval $(a,b)$ contains a point $p$ with gradient $1$?

I would guess no, but I've no idea how to prove it.

Now that I think about it, isn't this question similar to: Does there exist a non-constant differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that *every* interval $(a,b)$ contains a point $p$ with gradient $0$? Which I may or may not have seen on the site somewhere - can't remember. I guess the disproof would be something like: $f(x)$ has gradient $0$ almost everywhere $\implies f(x)$ has [unbounded variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation) somewhere (e.g. in some interval) $\implies$ f(x) is not everywhere differentiable. I'm not that familiar with bounded variation other than having skim-read [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/52b3w0/does_the_weierstrass_function_have_a_well_defined/) once, but bounded variation may in fact not be necessary to answer this question, I've no idea.

Maybe the mean value theorem is more relevant here.

Comment: Your condition is equivalent to $\{x\colon f^{\prime}(x)=1\}$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$. I don't see why that set would necessarily have full measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that yes, such a function exists.

The starting point is the [Pompeiu Derivative.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeiu_derivative).  To summarize Wikipedia, Pompeiu constructed an everywhere differentiable strictly increasing function $g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whose derivative $g'(x)$ is $0$ on a dense subset of $[0,1]$.  Call this dense set $D$.

Now, let $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,1)$ be your favorite diffeomorphism (e.g., you could pick $h(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(x) + \frac{1}{2}$.)

Set $f(x) = g(h(x)) + x$.   I claim that $f$ fulfills your criterion.  By the chain rule, $f'(x) = g'(h(x))h'(x) + 1$.  For $x\in h^{-1}(D)$, $g'(h(x)) = 0$, so $f'(x) = 1$ for $x\in h^{-1}(D)$.  Note that since $h$ is a diffeomorphism, it is a homeomorphism, so $h^{-1}(D)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is dense.  Lastly, since $g$ is strictly increasing, $f(x) -x$ is strictly increasing, so is not constant.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry I don't have not enough reputation points to comment instead of answering...)

I don't have the answer but you should get a look at Darboux's theorem and Darboux's functions or similar functions. I think you can find a non linear function $f$ such that the set $\{ x |f^\prime(x)=1\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Note that you can change your problem by asking that $\{ x |f^\prime(x)=0\}$ is dense (consider $x \mapsto f(x)-x$). This could help together with the mean value Darboux's theorem

Comment: You certainly make some relevant observations here.

Answer (score -1):

Is c a constant in (a,b) interval? If yes, you can try to prove it by contradiction, like using the function f(x) = x^2 in interval ]-1, 1[. I guess that's what you want.(Sorry about formatting, I'm ne here)

Comment: Basically, if $f(x)$ could equal $x+c$ for any real $c$ then the solution would be trivial. I'm not sure what $x^2$ on $ ]-1,1[ $ has to do with anything.

Comment: @Anunciada I think you're misinterpreting the hypothesis. It isn't saying that there is a point with derivative 1 in just one interval; it's saying that there is one of those points for *any* interval you consider.